# Laravel Eloquent accented characters issue

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, eloquent

I have a system that was initially built using MeekroDB and have been doing new development, as well as updating original development, to use Eloquent ORM.  I have having an issue with an accented e (é) character.

When pull from the database using Eloquent, I get the following:
TÃ©

But when pull from the database using MeekroDB, I get:
té

I thought the issue might be in passing the data to the front end, but even when printing to the php log I see the same values, so I'm thinking eloquent does some manipulation of a varchar when it's pulled from the database?

In an ideal world, I could properly encode the database value, but that's not a tenable solution at this time.  Using the meekro pulled value would also not be a terribly workable solution.

Has anyone else run into this issue before? Have any suggestions where to look ? Thanks.

Comment: You may need to change the charset/collation in the database configuration file.

Comment: Thank you, I just found out that was exactly the issue and came back to comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

The issue was that MeekroDB's encoding was set to utf8 where eloquent's was set to latin1.